# Calling javascript function in another directory from razorpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I cannot include a javascript file in my razorpages project. I want to be able to call functions from it, but not even an alert works.

I have included app.UseStaticFiles(); in startup.cs

My html is this:

```
@page
@model OptimalHousing.Pages.IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/site.js"></script>
    </head>
<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-page="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Dorm[0].dormName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Dorm[0].dormUrl)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Dorm)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dormName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dormUrl)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.id">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.id">Delete</a> |
                    <a asp-page="./GetAddress" asp-route-id="@item.id">Get address</a>
                    <input type="button" id="getSearchresultsButton" name="getCoordinates" value="Get searchresults" onclick="callGetFilteredDorms()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

</table>
<input type="button" id="getSearchresultsButton" value="Get searchresults" onclick="javascript: dope()" />
```

The file i try to include is site.js in this directory structure:
http://prntscr.com/oapg36

Comment: What function did you want to call from `site.js`? What do you mean not work? Do you receive any error in the web browser developer tool? For `site.js`, it will be loaded automatically by .net core with `Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` with `<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So some different things to consider in your page. First of all I think you want a structure where you have all of the basic HTML tags:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/site.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        {{PUT YOUR BODY HTML HERE}}
    </body>
</html>
```

If your javascript is properly mapped up and since you say that the `app.UseStaticFiles();` has been applied. First try to access the file by going to:

```
http://{{YOURDOMAINHERE}}/js/site.js
```

Do you get the actual javascript file? If not then it is not correctly mapped and you need to fix your configuration.

If it is I think the above line like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/site.js"></script>
```

Should work for you.

Another thing I see in your C# code is that you are using the first element of your array as the table header and then you later iterate over the same array of `Dorm`. This will print the same first element twice. Consider putting your table headers in their own variables instead of storing them in the array.

Comment: Adding the proper html structure worked, it was not included in the tutorial from the microsoft site, so i thought it wasn't necessary, thank you.